# /etc/ directory overwritten by mistake in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I've a running (installed fresh) Ubuntu 16 server. By mistake I've overwritten /etc/ directory with old backup of earlier server. As of now all seems to be working fine, unless some server(Postfix, Apache2 etc) is restarted.

I've yesterday's backup. If I restore yesterday's /etc backup what side-affect will be there?

Comment: You lose all your changes since yesterday?

Comment: @MichaelHampton So I lose only changes since yesterday only? Nothing else?

Comment: Apache not starting

Comment: Did you restore from your backup only, or did you mix your backup files from yesterday with files from a month ago (or whenever it was)?

Comment: I copied from yesterday only all files in /etc. But not worked

Comment: @MichaelHampton it seems if we untar /etc/ from earlier day backup in live server then only Apache does not work. I reinstalled only Apache now it's working. I hope nothing else breaks down